# Is it possible to add a new workbook based on a locked template

Tags: excel, vba

I've got the following VBA code which [Adds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.add) a new workbook based on a template.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddTemplatedWB()
    Workbooks.Add ( _
        "C:\VssBOX\Generic Projects\PMC2\template.xlsm" _
    )
End Sub
```

This works except when the template is locked. Then I get the usual password prompt:

[image]

Clicking Cancel gives me an error in VBA:

[image]

Is there any way to supply the password directly when adding the workbook? (This seems particularly weird since you can supply a password when [Opening](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) a file.)

If not, is there any other way to achieve what I'm looking for, i.e. creating a new file in memory based on a locked file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work for you, since you can supply the password during the call:

```
Public Sub AddTemplatedWB()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\VssBOX\Generic Projects\PMC2\template.xlsm", _
        Password:="YourPassword"
End Sub
```

---

**Edit**:

I was looking it up, but it seems that Microsoft didn't provide a direct way to do it. Maybe because they thought that it's not practical to lock a template with a password.

> One possible solution that pops to my mind is to create a copy of the
>   template and then opening it.

Comment: No, this opens the template. I want a new workbook based on a template.

Comment: I was looking it up, but it seems that Microsoft didn't provide a direct way to do it. Maybe because they thought that it's not practical to lock a template with a password. One possible solution that pops to my mind is to create a copy of the template and then opening it.

Comment: Can you accept my answer, since you used my solution to solve the issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, there doesn't seem to be any way to do this.

What I ended up doing instead is copying the template to a temporary file, [Opening](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) with the password.
Then I made sure that the temporary file was deleted after I was done with it.